# Multilinearity of the exterior derivative of a one-form.

Tags: manifolds, tensors

I wish to show that the exterior derivative $d \theta$ of a one-form $\theta$ is $\frak{F} \mathrm{(M)}$-multilinear, therefore, a tensor. Let $X, Y, V, W \in \frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$ and $f, g, h, k \in \frak{F} \mathrm{(M)}$ (smooth). If

$d \theta (X,Y) = X \theta Y - Y \theta X - \theta [X,Y]$

Then I must show that

$d \theta (fX + gY, hV + kW) = fh d \theta (X, V) + fk d \theta (X, W) + gh d \theta (Y,V) + gk d \theta (Y,W)$. (Is my equation right?)

Then I have to do the RHS to arrive at the LHS.

Is there another way to do this, perhaps easier, aside from brute force?

Comment: Also, I have to have a test function, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is right. A small simplification, if you already know that $d \theta (X,Y)=-d\theta(Y,X)$, is to just check that $d\theta(fX+gY,V)=f d\theta(X,V)+gd\theta(Y,V)$ as linearity in the second entry follows from antisymmetry and linearity in the first entry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is fine.

But to not get confused, try

$$d \theta (fX + gY, V) = f d \theta (X, V) +g d \theta (Y,V),$$

and

$$d \theta (X, hV + kW) = h d \theta (X, V) + k d \theta (X,W).$$